# Argument type is not assignable of type

Tags: angular, jasmine

I want to test a function and I have a problem with the type checking.

I am getting following error:

> Argument of type 'TestDates[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TestDates'.Property 'today' is missing in type 'TestDates[]'.

How can I solve it?

```
 it('should create the table', () => {
    const testDataMock = new DataItems([new TestDates(new Date(), new Date(), new Date())],
      [new DataTable('123456', date, 1.05728,
        undefined, -0.123, -0.123)]
    );
    const spy = spyOn(component, 'createTable');
    component.createMatrixTable(testDataMock);

    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

**TestDates**

```
export class TestDates {
  constructor(public today: Date,
              public lastMonth: Date,
              public lastDay: Date) {
  }
}
```

**createMatrixTable**

```
createMatrixTable(items: DataItems) {
    const {lastDay, lastMonth, today} = items.dateValues[0];
    const spreadOrQuote = this.data.type === 1 ? 'in' : 'out';
            this.createTable(items, columns);
          }
```

After test run I am getting the following message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'lastDay' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

The first param in `new DataItems(....` is an array of `TestDates`, I think it is expecting only a `TestDates` object, this is why you are getting `Argument of type 'TestDates[]' is not....`. Try this:

```
it('should create the table', () => {
    const testDataMock = new DataItems(new TestDates(new Date(), new Date(), new Date()),
      [new DataTable('123456', date, 1.05728,
        undefined, -0.123, -0.123)]
    );
    const spy = spyOn(component, 'createTable');
    component.createMatrixTable(testDataMock);

    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```